# Проблема с запуском приложение на Xamarin на эмуляторе Android

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

Только начал изучать программирование приложений на платформе XAMARIN. Столкнулся с проблемой, что не могу запустить даже самое стартовое приложение на эмуляторе. Вот скриншот параметров и ошибки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда я меняю базовое устройство на более старое, сталкиваюсь с проблемой:

Добавляю:
Выводится еще вот эта ошибка:

> не удается разрешить конфликт между "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" и "mscorlib,
>   Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e".
>   Произвольный выбор "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089".
>
> System UI isn`t responding

Все инструменты SDK у меня установлены

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот что выводится, когда использую старую версию устройства

```
Серьезность Код Описание    Проект  Файл    Строка  Состояние подавления
Ошибка      ADB1000:  Deployment failed
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Длина не может быть меньше нуля.
Имя параметра: length
   в System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)
   в Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidInstalledPackage..ctor(String value) в E:\A\_work\277\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\AndroidInstalledPackage.cs:строка 55
   в Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.ParseLastResortPackageList(String output) в E:\A\_work\277\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\Internal\AdbOutputParsing.cs:строка 65
   в Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass68_0.<GetPackagesLastResort>b__0(Task`1 t) в E:\A\_work\277\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\AndroidDevice.cs:строка 467
   в System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   в System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()          0
```

Comment: Версия студии какая? А Xamarin.Forms проекты запускаются?

Comment: Попробуйте пересобрать решение

Comment: @Bulson я к сожалению не знаю. Я правил свой вопрос, добавил информацию о конфликте версий mscorlib.